# Where is $config_directories value set in Acquia BLT?

Tags: 8, configuration, acquia-cloud

Generally to setup path for Config Directories,it is defined under
`settings.php` as

```
$config_directories['sync'] = 'path/to/config';
```

but in a blt setup when I checked

- settings.php
- sites/default/settings/local.settings.php
- /../vendor/acquia/blt/settings/blt.settings.php

I see there is no definition of

```
$config_directories['sync']
```

whereas in the documentation it says its defined here under vcs

> Although, by default, Drupal 8 uses the sync configuration directory
>   type for configuration, Acquia Cloud uses the vcs configuration
>   directory type for that purpose.
>   https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/develop/config-d8/#cloud-manage-local-config

But I still can't find the place where it is defined?

Comment: Have you looked in the admin UI under configuration management?

Comment: sorry I was looking into the codebase , is there any way I can find it in my codebase? or database? @leymannx